# How to design genetically advanced humans

Tags: warfare, genetic-engineering

You are an AI, who wants to create an army of genetically advanced humans to fight normal humans. (What is left of them.) Not to protect yourself, you could simply use a small fraction of your robot army to do that job. Not to extinct them, you could simply melt the earth mantle by placing some mirrors around the sun. You are programmed not to extinct humans. (Looks like they were not all stupid.) It's just because you want the humans to have somebody to fight, until they forget you. Of course your minions shall be able fighters. So here is the question: How would you design them?

Here are a few restrictions and facts about the world:

- Your minions must have a body similar to that of a human. They not only look the same, but they think like humans and they also need to survive by eating the same food, drinking the same liquids etc. More to the point they are genetically enhanced humans. Any cyborg (eg. partially robotic) technology is banned, too.
- Generally speaking they are about as intelligent as an average human. However they may be better in specific tasks.
- They need to do the job for several hundred years without your help.
- They cannot breed. That means they need a way to keep the casualties low.
- You removed modern technology from the humans. (pre black-powder society) Your minions therefore need to fight with ancient weapons, too. You want a fair fight after all. Okey semi-fair.
- They must not extinct humanity. When something unpredicted happens you can step in, of course, but you want to leave humanity alone for the next few hundred years. (Remember: You have a big plan and humanity is part of it.)
- You have next to unlimited resources available. (You can harvest jupiter if you want.) The same holds for energy and computing power. And of if you happen upon an intellectual problem, you'll be able to solve that somehow.

In case you didn't guess: I intend to write a story about a super intelligent AI with unknown goal.

Comment: And what's wrong with brainwashing some perfectly normal regular humans?

Comment: "They must not extinct humanity" - does it mean you need a "kill switch" for your apocalypse army?

Comment: Not that it matters much after the question being closed:
@Draco18s Somehow human-like but not human creatures pop up everywhere in literature. There are many reasons for them, for instance they are scary by nature

Comment: @Alexander I don't think they need that one. They just shouldn't get to strong

Comment: @lurch - genocide has very little to do with strength. Either your warriors are no more than a nuisance to humanity, or they are getting the upper hand, and before you know it, the humanity is gone.

Comment: Why not Space Marines? Not cyborg (unless heavy injury), can fight hand to weapon against most of modern weapons let alone pre black-powder society, live until death with no repercussion, eat normal food and drink water and they are bigger, stronger and smarter than your average mortal.

Answer (score 1):

With current knowledge/technology it's nowhere near possible to make genetic alterations like this, or give a reasonable answer how one could do it. Since your AI is not limited by seemingly anything, you don't have to care about that and can assume that the AI 'solved' the genetic code and knows exactly how to make anything happen.

The alterations I would propose:

- Unlimited, but slow, regeneration & immunity to diseases. This will keep the losses of your advanced humans low, while also encouraging them to not go 'all in' - they can be killed, but will always recover (after some days/weeks) otherwise. Therefore humanity should be able to hold fortified positions in a stalemate. It's the general purpose modification that also makes your advance humans last for several hunderte years.
- Very slightly enhanced strength & durability. Just enough to tilt any 'balanced' fight into the favour of the advanced humans, but not so much that normal humans can't win if they have the upper hand in numbers. It will ensure that your advanced humans never completely lose the war, since they have at least the same strategical capabilities as normal humans.

With those modifications the only important factor remaining is the initial number (and controlled area) of the normal and advanced human population. Since you have an all powerful AI, it can easily set the number & 'start position' of the advanced fighters so, that they will drive humanity into a closed area that will only support a limited number of humans, which is then never able to break out of a stalemate siege. (The advanced humans have unlimited resources/land for their population but they can't reproduce, so they also can not break the stalemate)